# How safe is it to visit Fiji and travel around Viti Levu in a car rental?

Tags: safety, car-rentals, security, corruption, fiji

I've been wanting to visit Fiji for awhile, rent a car and travel around the bigger island ([Viti Levu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viti_Levu)).  I was wondering how safe it is from corrupt police/military (there was a [coup d'etat](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2006_Fijian_coup_d%27%C3%A9tat) recently) and from general safety point of view (street crime, carjackings, etc.).  I would also prefer to stay in countryside B&Bs rather than large cities.

Comment: You may find [Wikitravel's Stay Safe section on Fiji](http://wikitravel.org/en/Fiji#Stay_safe) helpful, but it's a bit sparse (and maybe deserving of edits from anyone who answers here).

Comment: Not sure that 8 years ago really classifies as 'recently' but then he's still in power.

Comment: Canadian government is pretty warny: http://travel.gc.ca/destinations/Fiji click on Security but I'm planning on going anyway, not sure about driving around yet

Answer (score 2):

My only experience renting a car in Fiji worked out fine. We drove from Nadi down to Sigatoka and back.  This was prior to the 2006 coup but after the 2000 coup. Things will have changed since then, but the Fijian people are very friendly to outsiders and I would not have any concerns renting a car.